# Page doesn't Reload After printing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Page doesn't reloads after printing, using PHP laravel framework, tried all the available javascript and jquery page refresh and reload options, nothing is working, the below window.location.href works but printing doesnt happening, very much confused any help could be useful thanks. Using [Jquery print plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Print-Any-Part-Of-Your-Page-Print.html) and also tried window.print also.

```
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" id="mymodalss">Print</button>    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mymodalss").click(function(){

var deferredObj = $.Deferred();

 $.print("#offer",
        {
            deferred: deferredObj
        }
    );    
/*this way working with alert, if i remove alert it doesnt work*/
 deferredObj.done(function(value) {
         alert("Successful in Printing");
         window.location.href ="{{URL('/payroll/voucher')}}";      
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: It will only work when you click on the `#mymodalss` element...

Comment: have you checked `deferred: $.Deferred()` option available with this plugin. You need to call `window.location.href` code inside callback i.e. once printing is done.

Comment: ya, only that button.

Comment: @vijayP deferred doesnt work :( can u show some examples pls, thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try passing the `$.Deferred()` option while going for print like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mymodalss").click(function(){

    //declaring the deferred object in which page will get reloaded/refresh on .done event
    var deferredObj = $.Deferred();
    deferredObj.done(function(value) {
        window.location.reload(true);
    });

    $.print("#offer",
        {
            deferred: deferredObj
        }
    );    

  });

});
```

Comment: Ya tried but page doesnt reload only printing happening :(

Comment: can you try with this. Use `location.reload()` to reload the page.

Comment: can u please try adding a simple `alert` before `.reload()` to see if the code is getting executed or not?

Comment: not possible. `location.reload()` will obviously reload the page. It must be refreshing. Why do you think the page is not getting refreshed?

Comment: currently this is the problem if i add an`alert("hai")` and ` window.location.href ="{{URL('/payroll/voucher')}}"` it works perfectly, if i put only window.location alone without alert, it doesnt work, can u understand.

Comment: can you please try with `window.location.reload(true);`

Comment: or add a setTimeout around it like `setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(true);},100);`

Comment: Nope everything happening after the alert, not even timeout is working... :(

Comment: Sorry, but i dont have any clue about whats going wrong. Could you please modify your question with updated code which uses deferred code?

Comment: check now pls i have modified my question, and also if i cancel in printing that alert comes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115795/discussion-between-vijayp-and-crysis).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do simply `window.location.href="payroll/voucher"`.